# Send email SMTP from localhost with WAMP setup

Tags: zend-framework, smtp, localhost, zend-mail

I'm trying to configure my php.ini file so I can send emails from 'localhost' in my dev environment using PHP.  I no longer have access to an open SMTP server, and Gmail no longer works with their new SSL setup.  I've done a lot of research and seen lots of "solutions" here and elsewhere, but they don't work.  I've tried installing local SMTP servers (hMailServer asks for a password to install, Free SMTP Server doesn't work, etc).

Does anyone know of a free SMTP server I can setup in my php.ini file, or any other way to send mail from localhost (I just need it for testing purposes).  I don't want to have to change code and send emails in a completely different way when I switch to production.  (I'm using Zend and the Zend_Mail class)

Comment: if you are on a windows machine you could setup a SMTP server through IIS. Be sure your ISP doesn't block the port 25 if you setup the server on your local machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows I was usually using [Mercury](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercury.htm) to sent emails from localhost for testing purposes. Mercury is free for non-commercial use and it is also used in [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html).

Comment: Thanks!  After a little setup/config I was able to get Mercury setup as an SMTP server for localhost.  Works great!

Answer (score 3):

You could try using Zend_Mail_Transport_File for testing instead.

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->send(new Zend_Mail_Transport_File());
```

Comment: I don't want to have to switch code between dev and production.

Comment: Uhm, then put it in your bootstrap...
if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development') Zend_Registry::set('Transport', new Zend_Mail_Transport_File());
else Zend_Registry::set('Transport', new Zend_Mail_Transport_SMTP());
Then: $mail->send(Zend_Registry::get('Transport'));

Comment: With Transport_File, the email never actually gets sent.  This presents an issue with testing and QA since Outlook, GMail, Hotmail, etc, can all render emails very differently.  I need the emails to actually get sent in order to test them...

Answer (score 0):

Solution for XAMP, WAMP or etc..

download **hMailServer**; Then configure program:

1. When you first open hMailServer Administrator, you should add new domain.
2. Click on the "Add Domain ..." button at the Welcome page.
3. Under the domain text field, enter your computer's IP, in this case it should be 127.0.0.1.
4. Click on the Save button.
5. Go to Settings>Protocols>SMTP and select "Delivery of Email" tab
6. Enter "localhost" in the localhost name field.
7. Click on the Save button.

If you need to send mail using a FROM addressee of another computer, you need to allow deliveries from External to External accounts. To do that, follow these steps:

1. Go to Settings>Advanced>IP Ranges and double click on "My Computer" which should have IP address of 127.0.0.1
2. Check the Allow Deliveries from External to External accounts checkbox.
3. Save settings using Save button.

If you use Gmail account, then need small modification :

1. Go to Settings>Protocols>SMTP and select "Delivery of Email" tab
2. Enter "smtp.gmail.com" in the Remote Host name field.
3. Enter "465" as the port number
4. Check "Server requires authentication"
5. Enter your Google Mail address in the Username field
6. Enter your Google Mail password in the password field.
7. Check "Use SSL"

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use this confuguration for the transport of the mail

```
$transport = new Mail\Transport\Smtp();  
        $options = new Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions (array(  
                    'name' => 'host',  
                    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',  
                    'port'=> 587,  
                    'connection_class' => 'login',  
                    'connection_config' => array(  
                        'username' => "yourGmailUserMail",  
                        'password' => 'yourGmailPassword',  
                        'ssl'=> 'tls',  
                    ),  
        )); 
        $transport->setOptions($options)
```

;

and it will works.