# How do I send email using php via wamp?

Tags: wamp, wampserver, php

I want to use wamp as my development server and I'm trying to send email via my email => gmail, hotmail, yahoo. I'm trying to implement a simple email php application.

Is it possible to do it in wamp?

Is it possible to do it without changing php.ini and instead use ini_set();

I have tried changing my php.ini

```
using my yahoo mail
SMTP = smtp.mail.yahoo.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587
auth_user = me@yahoo.com    
auth_pass = password
```

and got this error message "Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 530 authentication required - for help go to http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/mail/pop/pop-11.html in C:\wamp\www\9dot_disc_alt\abc.php on line 12"

```
using gmail
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587
auth_user = me@gmail.com    
auth_pass = password
```

SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. pc6sm6631754pbc.47 in C:\wamp\www\9dot_disc_alt\abc.php on line 12

Here's my current code:

```
$to = "me@yahoo.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "me@my.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
```

Sir/Ma'am your answers would be of great help and be very much appreciated. Thank you++

Comment: Here is solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818444/send-email-smtp-from-localhost-with-wamp-setup/16814511#16814511

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an online article that allows me to send emails using wamp + php mailer

http://nikunj-solutions.blogspot.com/2011/08/send-email-using-wamp-server.html

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

When you use wamp, your SMTP must be your FAI, for example if you have free :

=>SMTP = smtp.free.fr (or .com)

EDIT : You can try this : http://glob.com.au/sendmail/, i's a simple windows console application that emulates sendmail's for wamp for example ;)

Comment: Sir, Thank you for the immediate reply. I would just like to ask is it possible to send emails via wamp without using other 3rd party applications?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to send email via wamp, you need to configure your SMTP.